# setvbuf() - size parameter when buf is NULL

Tags: c, glibc, stdio

It seems that when I run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    int i=0;

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF,0);

    while (1)
            printf("%d ",i++);

    return 0;
}
```

it prints in chunks of 1024 chars, no matter the **size** I define for setvbuf().
The question is is if **size** affects somehow in this case and where is the definition for 1024 chars is coming from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how you identified `1024` but it's probably `BUFSIZ`. `BUFSIZ` is defined in `stdio.h`.

> If buf is NULL, then the stdio library
>   automatically allocates a buffer for
>   use with stream (unless we select
>   unbuffered I/O).

**EDIT**

Here's something `glibc` says:

> Macro: int BUFSIZ
>   The value of this macro is an integer constant expression that is
>   good to use for the size argument to
>   setvbuf. This value is guaranteed to
>   be **at least 256**.
>
> The value of BUFSIZ is chosen on each system so as to make stream I/O
>   efficient. So it is a good idea to use
>   BUFSIZ as the size for the buffer when
>   you call setvbuf.

**EDIT 2**

@larsmans is right. I looked at how `setvbuf` is implemented and it ignores a call when asking for line buffering and presenting a NULL buf. Now, `stdout` is no ordinary file, it's attached to a terminal. So, heading over to [pixelbeat](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/)

> - Buffer size only directly affects    buffered mode
> - The default size like the kernel is    based on the page size (4096 bytes on 
>     my system)
> - if stdin/stdout are connected to a    terminal then default size = 1024;
>     else size = 4096

Comment: Unlikely; on my Linux/glibc system, `BUFSIZ == 8192`.

Comment: @larsmans On mine too; but I just ran it on VS 2008 and there `BUFSIZ == 512`. Plus, I *still* don't know if it's actually `1024`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the (draft) C standard,

> If `buf` is not a null pointer, the array it points to may be used instead of a buffer allocated by the `setvbuf` function and the argument `size` specifies the size of the array; otherwise, `size` **may** determine the size of a buffer allocated by the `setvbuf` function. [Emphasis added.]

So, assuming you measured correctly, it seems like Glibc is free to do as it pleases when `buf` is null, and it gives you a 1kB buffer. Since you never write a newline, line buffering has no effect and the behavior is similar to full buffering.

Answer (score 0):

The size probably doesn't have much effect for a NULL buf pointer.

However, you are still requesting buffered output with `_IOLBF` Try `_IONBF` instead.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setvbuf