# setvbuf() - buffer size when buf is NULL

Tags: c, io, buffer

I have already read the answer to a *similar* [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088735/setvbuf-size-parameter-when-buf-is-null) but i am more interested in stream buffering when performing I/O with files.

When I run the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    printf("%d\n", BUFSIZ);

    FILE *fp = fopen("ekomi.txt", "wb");

    char array[2] = {'a', 'b'};
    fwrite(array, sizeof(char), 2, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

it prints BUFSIZ = 8192.
As far as i understand BUFSIZ should be the value used by glibc for the size of the buffer created by default after fopen (which, as far as i understand, should be the same as calling setvbuf passing a NULL pointer to the parameter buf).
I ran this program with massif and the output clearly shows that the buffer allocated by glibc is 4096 Bytes long

[massif output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krtTz.png)

The GNU C library documentation itself is not clear about the default size of the buffer:

> If you specify a null pointer as the buf argument, then setvbuf allocates a buffer itself using malloc. This buffer will be freed when you close the stream.

So my question is, how does glibc decide how much memory to allocate for the buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: BUFSIZ is the maximum buffer size allowed, but the one used in the malloc is given by the filesystem blocksize.

Long answer:
Let's trace back what setvbuf does when we let pass a NULL pointer as buf.

https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/iosetvbuf.c#l60

```
_IO_DOALLOCATE (fp)
```

https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/libioP.h#l237

```
#define _IO_DOALLOCATE(FP) JUMP0 (__doallocate, FP)
```

Here it's calling a "__doallocate" function associated to the FILE vtable with the **JUMP0** macro, and it gets ending up calling **_IO_file_doallocate()** defined here:

https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/filedoalloc.c#l97

```
#if _IO_HAVE_ST_BLKSIZE
    if (st.st_blksize > 0 && st.st_blksize < _IO_BUFSIZ)
        size = st.st_blksize;
#endif
```

In the aforementioned line you can see what I was mentioning in the short answer. It's using the **stat64** struct (https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat64) to retrieve the blocksize of the filesystem and setting size accordingly if it is less than BUFSIZ.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.